# Angular schema form - insert data using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angular-schema-form

I am going to insert data into a database using angular schema form, but how can I post schemaForm data into PHP, What is wrong in my code, and please let me know how can I learn about Schema form documentation.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['schemaForm']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Comment",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "title": "Name",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
};

  $scope.form = 
  [
    "name",
    {
      "type": "submit",
      "style": "btn-info",
      "title": "Submit",
      "onclick":insert()
    }
  ];


  $scope.model = {};


  $scope.insert=function()
  {
    $http.post("insert.php",
    {
      'name' :$scope.schema[name]
    }).then(function(response)
    {
      console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
    },
    function(error)
    {
      alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

});
```

This is my PHP Code to do the database connectivity,

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "demo", "angular");
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo $info->name;
if (count($info) > 0) 
{
    $name     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->name);
    $query = "INSERT INTO crud(name) VALUES ('$name')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) 
    {
        echo "Data Inserted Successfully...";
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Failed';
    }
}
?>
```

Please help

Comment: Have to print data at PHP page you are getting anything there which is posted from angular?

Comment: you are using json_decode on the PHP side...but have you checked whether the Javascript is actually sending JSON? It doesn't look like it would, I should think it will send normal formurl-encoded data. Check your network tools in the browser and inspect the body of the ajax request, see what it looks like. There's a good chance you can simply use $_POST["name"] on the PHP side to get the input value. (P.S. You've given us such little information that I don't think you have spent enough time debugging this before asking your question).